# I need a recurrence relation or function for a series [Solved]

Tags: series-expansion, difference-equations

I am not sure if what I need is a function or a recurrence relation to extend what you see below to substantial n.

[image]

In words:

I have a series. Starting with `n=3` (`n={0,1,2}` are ignored for the moment), we calculate `2π` divided by `n` times the earlier result, not prior from but TWO ITERATIONS AGO.

The solution to `n=1`, which you need for the first calculation (two prior) in the series (which we start with 3) is `(2 π)/π`

I have done some factoring to find some interesting patterns:

1. The numerator of all factors is always `2π`.
2. When `n` is odd, the denominator starts with `n` and declines, in steps of two (to remain odd) until the last which is π
3. When `n` is even, the denominator starts with `n` and declines, in steps of two (to remain even) until the end (see example result ten  below)
4. In the results, the exponents of π occur in pairs, two squared, followed by two cubed, followed by two to the fourth $\ldots$

Here are the first eight results using brute force.

```
{(4 π)/3, π^2/2, (8 π^2)/15, π^3/6, (16 π^3)/105, π^4/24, (32 π^4)/945, π^5/120}
```

As an image for ease of viewing here
[image]

Here is the first result (for `n=3`)

```
(2 π)/3 (2 π)/π
```

> (*4 π/3*)

```
% == (4 π^2)/(3 π)
```

> (*True*)

Here is the tenth result (as an image)

[image]

Thanks to @Domen for nailing it. Using

```
c[1]==2,c[2]==π
```

leads to this:

```
dimFct[n_] := π^(n/2)/Γ[1 + n/2]
```

Comment: Take a look at [`RSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html), for example: ``RSolve[{c[n] == 2 Pi c[n - 2]/n, c[1] == 2, c[2] == 2}, c[n], n]``. Not that you need two initial values, that is, you have to provide $C_1$ _and_ $C_2$.

Comment: [Original](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor) post and the [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mathematica-editor-button/jelneigihibbkognjehbbembccihhbnb) to buttons at the Chrome web store.

Comment: BTW, this code allows reproduction of the Table on page 144 (whatever that means for a Kindle Version) in Chapter 9 of Richard Hamming's incredible book "The Art of Doing Science and Engineering: Learning to Learn" which is the perfect book for guys like me who think that reconciling mathematics with computer science will lead you to The TRUTH.